# Disable Badly-Designed Form Element

Tags: windows-7, cpu, html

One of our suppliers has a badly-designed website. On this website, there is a HTML [select](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) tag which has, over the years, grown to over 10,000 options long. This is apparently enough to cause large CPU spikes, using the latest versions of IE, Chrome or Firefox. On our lower-spec Windows 7 PCs, this can freeze the browser entirely for 10-15 seconds. As this page gets loaded regularly, this is draining producivity on those users.

The supplier is currently working on fixing the issue, but they're slow to get a fix in place. Is there anything I can do in the meantime to either prevent this option list from loading (whilst still loading the rest of the page) or to alleviate the CPU spikes more quickly?

I have already put the PC in High Performance (as opposed to Power Saver) mode so that the CPU ramps up more quickly. I've also looked at GreaseMonkey type scripts, however it looks like these can only hide the element (still loading it and incurring the CPU load), not prevent it from loading entirely. The name of the select object is unique and is in the format x_12345.

Comment: Does the <select> element have a name or ID?

Comment: The <select> name is unique, I've added that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can download an extension for chrome called ABP (Adblock Plus).

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb?hl=en-US

Once installed, there will be an icon that looks like a stop sign next to the address bar in Chrome.

Visit the webpage in question, then left click on the ABP icon.

On the window that opens up, select "**Block Element**", then move your mouse to the select element you would like to hide and right click it (it will appear yellow)

Select **Add** in the next window that appears.

Going forward, that element will not be displayed when you visit that page.

If you made a mistake, or would like to view the blocked element again, just click on the ABP icon again, click **options**, then remove the block on the "**Add your own filters**" Tab.

hope it helps.